how to change JDK for Android Studio from 21 to jdk 17?
I use android studio ladybug 24.2.1 In this version، GDK v-21 is Build-in
how to change JDK for Android Studio from 21 to jdk 17.
JDK for Android toolchain is 17  and Android Studio is 21. I want to use JDK 17 for both of them.
This screenshot shows JDK 21 being used for Android Studio:


Why do you want to change the JDK Android Studio is running with. Android Studio comes with built-in JDK. I don't think you can change that. usually you only need to change the JDK gradle is running with - is that what you call "JDK for Android toolchain"?

Check Installed JDKs, Ensure the desired JDK version is installed.
Open Android Studio Preferences
Open Android Studio.
Go to Preferences -> Navigate to JDK Settings
In the Preferences window, go to:
Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle. Change the JDK Path

Under "Gradle JDK," click the dropdown and select your desired JDK version.


I had a similar issue with not being able to set it via studio so the easiest way

Download jdk separately.
Configure my project to use 17

flutter config --jdk-dir yourJDK path


Optionally (Some plugins may require) update

sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
jvmTarget = '17'




To change Android Studio's JDK, follow these steps:
1 Go to File > Project Structure.
2 Select the SDK Location section in the list of the left.
3 Deselect the Use embedded JDK (recommended) option.
4 Enter the absolute path of your installed JDK in the text box
5 Digi also recommends you lower the default memory setting for Gradle (org.gradle.jvmargs property):
◦ Create a file called Gradle. Properties in the root of your project
The reference I used is the website of my university.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you use version manager like fvm,

Make sure your desired version set as global

do this command to change desired JDK version
flutter config --jdk-dir "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4"


Restart IDE or terminal, Happy coding

Here's what I did on my machine...
You can download Java 17 SDK based on your machine. Here's the link
After you download and install it.
Please go to your Android Studio's File > Project Structure...
Then select your installed Java SDK by this way:

Note: You can also verify there if you properly selected the corresponding Java SDK.
After selecting, click apply, and then ok.
Please consider doing File > Invalidate Caches...
After doing these things. Execute flutter doctor -v again.
Make sure you set the proper PATH and JAVA_HOME in your ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES. Here's what I set for PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin and for JAVA HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17 it should be added in your system variables section.
For instant checking of your PATH and JAVA_HOME setup,
In Windows, open your command prompt, then execute these commands:
for checking your PATH
where java

for checking your JAVA_HOME
echo %JAVA_HOME%

UPDATE
Here's the related answer to the OP's case: you may please visit this answer
I hope it helps!

It works for me in this way. I hope others verify it if they find something to clarify here. I will appreciate it because it will help others as well.
